# Elementwise operation between two NumPy arrays of same shape but arbitrary number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

i have two numpy arrays A and B which have the same shape and dimension. I want to do an elementwise operation on the two arrays. the elementwise operation is a bit complex, but I want it to run for any arbitrary binary operation.

If I have to write a program for elementwise multiplication for a given array dimension, say 2D, it is easy. Like so

```
def elementwise_operator(A,B):
    assert A.shape == B.shape
    C = np.zeros_like(A)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            C[i,j] = A[i,j] * B[i,j]
    return C
```

But I cannot extend it to 3D, or 4D or any arbitrary dimensions because I do not know how many for-loops I need.

Comment: what is the elementwise operation? You should not use loops with numpy. Just do `C = A*B`.

Comment: Let's say its something a bit more involved than simple math operators. Eg. max(0, A-B). Else I'd have gone the matrix multiplication way

Comment: Then `C = np.maximum(A-B, 0)`, again you should **not** use loops with numpy. Please be explicit, which operation do you need to run?

Comment: If you can't provide a clear description of the operation, then the question should be closed. Numpy is not designed to use loops, use lists of lists instead.

Comment: Okay, I agree. Thank you. Your comment solves my immediate implementation blocker. I will look up similar numpy operations if I have to perform more complicated binary operations.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep this in mind if I don't fina a way to express binary operators in simple math operations.

Comment: Read the official basic documentation.  There's a large set of operators and `ufunc` functions that operate elementwise.